# How to store file into hyperledger fabric using hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In model file, We have have 'string' data type to store any string. However; If I would like to store file into hyperledger fabric using hyperledger composer, then is there any specific data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the reference [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/cto_language.html), the `string` type contains UTF-8 encoded character sequences. Therefore, you cannot just put the bytes of a file into a `string`.

One of the possible solution is encoding the file into a base64 (`uudncode`, `base64encode`, etc.) string first, and then store it in a `string` field.

Based on your requirements (personal data regulations, etc.), you may want to store the file off-chain, and store only the cryptographic hash (SHA-1, SHA-256, etc.) of the file in the chain (as a `string`).

Comment: You're welcome! Please also support me by voting +1 on the answer. Thanks!

Comment: When I am storing data in a String value in asset it throws error as "large file".